# Rearrange table head data to match with table body

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to arrange the table head with my table body, so the data fill have a same type, how can i doing it??

[The black square is the correct one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upgdh.png)

This is my code

```
<table>
                    $syntax = 'SELECT customer,type, count(type) as num FROM view_detail GROUP BY type ORDER BY customer';
                    $rows = $config->prepare($syntax);
                    $rows->execute();
                    $result = $rows->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                ?>  
            </tr>
                <td>No</td>
                <td>Customer</td>
                <?php for($x=0;$x<count($result);$x++){ ?>
                    <td><?php echo $result[$x]->type; ?></td>
                <?php  } ?>
                    <td>Total</td>
                <?php $no = 1;

                    $query = 'SELECT customer,type, count(type) as tipe FROM view_detail GROUP BY customer ORDER BY customer';
                    $baris = $config->prepare($query);
                    $baris->execute();
                    $hasil1 = $baris->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

                    for($i=0;$i<count($hasil1);$i++){
                        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM view_detail WHERE customer = "'.$hasil1[$i]->customer.'" ORDER BY customer';
                        $row = $config->prepare($sql);
                        $row->execute();
                        $hasil = $row->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);                
                ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $no; $no++;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $hasil[$i]->customer; ?></td>
                <?php 
                    for($y=0;$y<count($result);$y++){
                        if($y < count($hasil)){
                ?>
                    <td><?php echo $hasil[$y]->type; ?></td>
                <?php }else{ ?>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <?php } } }?>
            </tr>
    </table>
```

Thanks

[I want to make it like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaK9L.png)

Edit:
Dynatrade -> MFN200, N50Z, and N70
Super Bloom -> N70, MFN100, MFN120, and MFN150

Comment: My first guess would be you are missing some 'colspan' around. Can you give us a visual of how you expect the final result to be?

Comment: i want to match the record with the table head,